# Capturing a repeated group using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to build a comma separated list of the items. The items are made up of what is in the quotes embedded in expression similar to the following two examples.

The list is from a session file, comprising a starting text identifier, followed by a or s to indicate array/string, a number to indicate how many items in the array (0 if there is no array) - here's a couple of examples:

```
extralistids|a:3:{i:0;s:3:"id1";i:1;s:4:" id2";i:2;s:4:" id3";}
extralistids|s:0:"";
```

I've got the following preg_match expression but it only captures "id3" - any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

```
/extralistids.+?(?:{).*?("(.*?)"(?:.*?))+;(?:})/
```

Comment: A capture group only captures one repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the string `extralistids` in your pattern then try the below regex.

```
(?:\bextralistids\||(?<!^)\G)[^"]*\"([^"\n]*)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/12)

```
<?php
$mystring =<<<EOT
extralistids|a:3:{i:0;s:3:"id1";i:1;s:4:" id2";i:2;s:4:" id3";}
extralistids|s:0:""
EOT;
$regex = '~(?:\bextralistids\||(?<!^)\G)[^"]*\"([^"\n]*)"~';
preg_match_all($regex, $mystring, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id1
    [1] =>  id2
    [2] =>  id3
    [3] => 
)
```